# If $T$ is an onto linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, then the range of $T$ is $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand this statement: If $T$ is an onto linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, then the range of $T$ is $W$.

I learned a corollary to theorem today.

In the proof of the corollary, it states exactly what I typed in the title. Just curious how to make sense of $R(T) = W$ (the co-domain).

Comment: Isnt this self-evident? If T hits everything in W, then T(V)=W? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It is now since Alonso laid out the logic step-by-step. It just really helps me to have an explanation that deliberately travels through the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T: V \to W$ is onto, then for every $w \in W$, we have a $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=w$, this gives $$W \subset T(V).$$ And of course, since $T(v) \in W$ for all $v \in V$ then $$T(V) \subset W.$$ By double inclusion  $Range(T):=T(V)=W$

Comment: Glad to help! note that in the other texts you will encounter this as the definition of onto, i.e. $f:X\to Y$ is $onto$ iff $f(X)=Y$. Now you know both definitions are equivalent.